# Macro redefining logical operators

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming so please forgive me if this sounds like a dumb thing to do.

I had an idea in attempt to make my code a bit more readable and the idea is to `#define`  logical operators such as `#define OR ||`.

If anyone can direct me is this bad or good practice, is it common etc... and also if it has any side effects, I would be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen that.  Not a good idea.  Use the proper, native operator syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternate names for this and other operators are already part of standard C. Using `#include <iso646.h>` defines:

| Name | Replacement |
| --- | --- |
| and | && |
| and_eq | &= |
| bitand | & |
| bitor | | |
| compl | ~ |
| not | ! |
| not_eq | != |
| or | || |
| or_eq | |= |
| xor | ^ |
| xor_eq | ^= |

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer because it pointed out it's already a thing ! I guess it would look a bit better for my embedded class codes. +1 !

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil I suggest avoiding `iso646.h` and learning to use the traditional operators. You should strive to write code that's easy to understand, and `iso646.h` isn't widely used.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the tip. The traditional operators look so obfuscated and I'm finding it hard to debug with all those characters throwing me off. So maybe when I get comfortable enough I'll start using them.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil The only way to become comfortable with them is to actually use them. There is no other way.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil That sounds like a sign that your expressions needs refactoring.

Comment: or_eq and xor_eq are quite confusing because there is no equality check there

Comment: This header file is provided mainly for development environments where it is difficult or impossible to type the native operator characters according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens). The name stems from the ISO646 that defines a standard character set, which does not necessarily include these characters. -- Additionally I found its usage to be mandatory where code verifiers with a lack of C knowledge are on duty. -- Bottom line: don't do this.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil C operators are virtually universal across mainstream languages - C++, C#, Java, Rust, Go, Javascript, Python for the most part - you will see these operators **everywhere**.  You should get comfortable with them and not with esoteric replacement definitions that won't port to any other language.

Answer (score 7):

Don't.

A C coder is expected to read such operators like it was plain English. And also, you would not do the same for the operators +, -, / and *, right? Logicians does not write or. They use symbols. So instead, just get used reading them.

If I saw the expression `if(x OR y)` in a piece of code, my first thought would be *"This must be a beginner"* and my next thought would be *"Did they do it right and used `||` or did they use a single `|`?"* I better check this up just to make sure.

> is it good practice

My opinion is definitely no

> is it common

No, because most C coders share my opinion

> and also if it has any side effects

Not really. It's a macro, so it's simple cut and paste.

And just for completeness. It does exist a standard header that does what you want called `iso646.h`. But it's rarely used. I had never seen it before Eric posted his answer. So if you want to do this, then use that header instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you sir for the detailed explanation, I am indeed a beginner like you said.

Answer (score 3):

1. Never use Macros without prefix
2. see the answer of klutt
3. What's more readable:

- (a + b) * c
- (a PLUS b) MULT c

If you want to make code more readable, do that on a higher level, e.g.

```
if ((x >= y) && (x < z))
```

implement a function/macro with a meaningful naming, e.g.

```
#define IN_RANGE(X, MIN, MAX) ((X) >= (MIN)) && ((X) < (MAX))

if (IN_RANGE(x, min, max))
```

Comment: The IN_RANGE example is very interesting, it resembles Python syntax , Thank you !

Comment: Reducing complexity is the main rule, at least in my opinion. Happy coding.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük *Beware*: your `IN_RANGE` macro will have unexpected behavior if called like this: `IN_RANGE(x++, 0, 1)` (because of side-effects, etc). Not that it's a bad idea, generally speaking, to simplify coding using macros, but this is just a remainder that macros must be used carefully.

Comment: @LucaPolito You're absolutely right, Macro Pitfalls are a real thing. As you realized, the main emphasis was not on Macros in general but what can be done to produce more readable code. But nevertheless a good idea to point it out, since the OP said himself, that he's new to the C language.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Yes, indeed, my comment was to warn inexperienced programmers (not you).

Answer (score 1):

```
#define logOR ||
#define bitOR |
```

This may be the one reason why here symbols were chosen, as with `+` etc. There is not one "or", so it gets lost in a sea of variable names.

side effect:

```
   if (x||y)
   if (xORy)
```

The `xORy` one does not work - unless such variable is declared, which would be very confusing, in combination.

---

### _eq

```
#define or_eq |=
```

Now this is actually the argument against it; `or=` and `or =` do not work, so good-bye to the assignment operator `=` also.

```
a = a PLUS 4   // acceptable - an assignment
a PLUS_EQ 4    // ??? assembler?
```

Comment: Good point - you would need whitespace around the `OR`, otherwise the compiler would treat `xORy` as a single identifier, not as a logical expression.  `|` and `&` can never be part of an identifier, so you don't need whitespace to get `x||y` to be parsed properly.

Comment: Experienced developers don't write source code _without_ whitespace around binary operators.

Comment: @thebusybee Depends. Using it around ALL binops don't improve readability. For instance, I'd write something like `(a+b) * (b+c)` rather than `(a + b) * (b + c)`

Comment: If that is permitted by your style guide, well, then it's obviously OK. Style guides are a must. For me it still "jumps" into my eyes as `atb` and `ctd` and I wonder why the parentheses are there. It's always a matter how much time we need to grasp the code.

Answer (score 1):

> If anyone can direct me is this bad or good practice, is it common etc... and also if it has any side effects, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

It is not common practice, and in my experience it creates maintenance problems (such as doing a global search and replace to change an "and" to an "or" in several string literals and breaking code because someone else decided to use `and` instead of `&&` and `or` instead of `||`).

Straight C code can be a bit eye-stabby, and generations of programmers have tried to use the preprocessor to redefine operators or delimiters to something easier to read (such as Pascal programmers redefining `{` and `}` as `BEGIN` and `END`, Fortran programmers redefining `&&` and `||` to `AND` and `OR`, etc.).  The problem is no two programmers do it the same way, and you just wind up with an unmaintainable mess.  Then an experienced C programmer comes in, says "what's all this garbage", and rips it all out anyway, like I wound up doing after the situation I described above.

Resist the urge to create macros for standard delimiters and operators.  You just make your code harder to understand and maintain for other C programmers.